# Difference between location and if $request_uri

Tags: nginx

What is the difference between this?

```
location ~ /path/ {
  set $skip_cache 1;
}
```

And

```
if ($request_uri ~* "(/path/)") {
  set $skip_cache 1;
}
```

In my experiments, I noticed that the first one includes all sub-paths, and the other one only the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right! The main difference is that with the first one you just look for content that starts/ends with the parameters you specify, and the second one returns the full path to the page you've visited, including all the arguments ("?" and "&") you pass in the URL.

For more information, you can read these two posts, which I find interesting:

- Location directive: https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-location-directive
- $request_uri: https://www.webhosting24.com/understanding-nginx-request_uri/